# Selenium (Java) + Angular 7: Check if MatRadioButton is checked

Tags: javascript, java, angular, selenium

Assume the following (simplyfied) code:

## Angular

```
<mat-radio-group id="group" ...>
      <mat-radio-button id="xyz" value="val" ...>I'm a radio button
      </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group id="group>
```

This radio button is checked by default (using ReactiveForms).

## Selenium

I wait for the element to be present and returning it afterwards.

```
    private By btn = By.id("xyz");
```

But I can't validate if the radio button is selected:

```
    assertTrue(btn.isSelected()); // <--- not working
```

## Hints

1. Looking at the DOM, there is no attribute called `checked`
2. Analyzing all attributes of the `WebElement` via `JavascriptExecutor` tells the same story as 1):

`{_ngcontent-vvq-c7=..., class=..., id=..., style=..., tabindex=..., value=...} tostring [[RemoteWebDriver: ...)] -> id: ...]`

3. `Augury` states that there is an attribute called `_checked=true` during inspection

## Edit

Turns out `Angular` dynamically adds a `css` class called `mat-radio-checked` to the element whenever it has been checked.
In return, it will remove the class, if the `radio button` isn't selected.

In my `Selenium` test, I can validate this behaviour like

```
assertEquals("... mat-radio-button mat-accent mat-radio-checked", btn.getAttribute("class"));
```

But this is kind of hard coded - there must be another way.

## Question

How can I check if the radio button is selected via `Selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you first want to access the element present inside the webdriver instance using the following line:

```
private By btn = By.id("xyz");
WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(btn);
```

Doing above thing will make sure the below assertion works.

```
assertTrue(radioButton.isSelected()); // <--- not working
```

Comment: But I do know that the radio button is already selected because I take a snapshot before doing my assertion. Why do I need to click() it again?

Comment: So you do not need to write that line of code, just execute it without that it should work

Comment: Just to make it clear for me: With your solution, I would actively click on the radio button myself, right? But I don't want to manipulate the state of the radio button - I just would like to know if it is checked already as soon as I enter the view.

Comment: I got your point, I was saying just delete that line from your code and it will work. I just gave you that line for reference in case it was not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Just some details for correct Prince's answer.

`isSelected()` is a method of `WebElement` and `By` class **does not have** this method. That's the reason `assertTrue(btn.isSelected());` is not working.

`WebElement` interface represents node(element) in the html page and `By` is a helper class to locate and assign your elements. For example, `findElement​(By by)` takes `By` as argument and it will return instance for `WebElement`.

Links:
[WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) 
[By](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html)